# Can't find wrapper class definition

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I am modifying inherited code in the apex controller.  There is a WrapperJobs object that is returned.  However, I cannot find the object definition anywhere. 
 Can you point me to where it could be.

```
    @AuraEnabled
global static WrapperJobs getJobs(Integer numberOfJobs,
        Integer numberOfJobsPerPage,
        String strfilterType,
        String strRecordId,
        String netwrkId,
        String sortBy,
        String filterByTopic,
        String filterByAuthor,
        String filterByOrganization,                                      
        String topicName,
        String filterOn,
        String searchTerm,
        String fromDate,
        String toDate) {
    DateTime fromDt;
    DateTime toDt;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WrapperJobs` is not a standard object. Its location can only be divined by inspection of your codebase.

The easiest way to do this will be to use Visual Studio Code or another IDE to retrieve all Apex classes from your Salesforce org. You'll then be able, at minimum, to search across your code for `class WrapperJobs` to find the definition; your IDE may also provide a "jump to definition" function.

It's common for wrapper classes to be defined as inner classes in the file in which they're used. You may locate the definition inside a top-level class in this file.

Comment: I retrieved the code to Visual Studio and found the wrapper class definition by searching on it.  Thanks!